# fopen() very slow when used in Joomla

Tags: php, rest, joomla, fopen, joomla-extensions

I'm writing a authentication plugin for Joomla. 
The plugin is calling an external site to verify the username and password.

The code works, but my problem is that when I'm calling fopen() from the Joomla plugin, it takes a very long time (63 seconds) for it to respond.

When running the same code on the server (but not through Joomla), the fopen() call only takes 0.1 second.

Is there any settings that Joomla can have changed, that makes the fopen() call taking so long? Or is there any other function that I should use instead of fopen()? (I have tried file_get_contents() but with the same result)

Below is the code I'm using (based on this article: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/) (I don't have cURL installed so that is not an option.)

```
$username = "admin";
$password = "1234" ;
$verb = 'GET'
$url = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api.phtml/login" ;

$params = array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$password);    
$params = http_build_query($params);
$url .= '?' . $params;

$cparams = array( 'http' => array(  'method' => $verb,
                                    'ignore_errors' => true ) );

$context = stream_context_create($cparams);
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
```

The allow_url_fopen is enabled.

Joomla! Version: Joomla! 2.5.27 Stable
PHP Version: 5.2.6-1+lenny10

I have been struggeling with this for three days now, so any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: avoid passing password as a get parameter(in url), not at all secure. And I think server is taking time to respond. how much time does the browser take to load joomla site ?

Comment: If I disable my plugin, the page takes 1,16s to load when I click login, and if I enable my plugin, the page takes 1m 4s to load. I did put `$time = microtime(true);` just before and after the fopen() call and that's how I came up with 63 seconds. About passing the password in the URL, I thought it was secure when using https?

Comment: can you runa test on webpagetest.org for https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api.phtml/login? Hast the DNS been changed for this recently? May be try curl instead of fopen and try a different hosting company.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about webpagetest.org! Never heard about it before. The result from that page was "Document loaded in 0.6 seconds". About DNS, I have tried using the IP-number instead and I still get the same result. If I use my code "outside" Joomla, and on the same server, it works perfect, but when I run the code as a plugin, that's when it takes 63 seconds to load. My plugin is based on this code: [Creating an Authentication Plugin for Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla). Thanks a lot for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we have a problem with fopen, we switch to curl and that solves the problem. In any case, check your .htaccess and your local php.ini (or .user.ini) files for the Joomla site for any restrictions on fopen.